# Hibernate second level cache with Spring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, jakarta-ee

I'm using Spring + JPA + Hibernate. I'm trying to enable Hibernate's second level cache. In my Spring's `applicationContext.xml` I have:

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path">/ehcache.xml</prop>
```

When I run I get the error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate cache implementation
     at org.hibernate.cache.CacheFactory.createCache(CacheFactory.java:64)

Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.NoCachingEnabledException: Second-level cache is not enabled for usage [hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache | hibernate.cache.use_query_cache]
     at org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider.buildCache(NoCacheProvider.java:21)
```

So it's complain I don't have second level cache enabled. I attempt to enable it by adding to my `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
```

But still no joy. I also tried adding this to my ehcache.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
```

But it still doesn't work. Changing the `provider_class` to `org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider` doesn't help either:

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
```

My entity classes are annotated to use caching

```
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
```

So, how do I enable second level cache?

**Edit:**  This is under the bean:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
```

**Resolved:** Since I'm using `LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean` it gets its settings from `META-INF/persistence.xml`. My settings in `applicationContext.xml` weren't even being read.

Comment: In which bean are you setting those props?

Comment: entityManagerFactory, which is the same bean as where I set hibernate.dialect, which Hibernate does read

Comment: I don't know about JPA, we have it under hibernateProperties in org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean

Comment: Yeah I tried sticking it under hibernateProperties and it has the same problem. It's basically not read the "hibernate.cache.provider_class" property.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I didn't answer this, but it's not obvious that the poster found the answer himself.  I'm reposting his answer:

#### Resolved

Since I'm using `LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean` it gets its settings from `META-INF/persistence.xml`. My settings in `applicationContext.xml` weren't even being read.

Comment: I am setting it as JPAProperties while creating  LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean bean. Still, I am getting the same error. Any sugeestions??

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">4</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
```

And if you are using Maven add this to your POM file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
  <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Or download the latest jar from http://ehcache.org/

Comment: The max_fetch_depth option is unnecessary for the purpose of the cache, and setting it to '4' is probably undesirable as it allows a large number of joins to happen on the SQL query. On a large database, queries can return millions of results and take forever to execute and reduce into a usable entity. max_fetch_depth is '2' by default.

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/hibernate) helped me for using second level cache with Hibernate 4