# maven + spring mvc 3 + jpa + hibernate + ehcache

Tags: hibernate, spring, maven-2, jpa, ehcache

I am getting the following exception when I run my sample project in embedded jetty inside maven.

```
org.hibernate.cache.NoCachingEnabledException: Second-level cache is not enabled for usage [hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache | hibernate.cache.use_query_cache]
    at org.hibernate.cache.impl.NoCachingRegionFactory.buildEntityRegion(NoCachingRegionFactory.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1341)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:669)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:132)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:225)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:546)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:872)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:491)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection$1.run(HandlerCollection.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:450)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

here is my properties in persistence.xml

```
<properties> 
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
        <!-- <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" /> -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none" /> 
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />


        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory"/>
        <!-- Enable/Disable the second-level cache --> 
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/> 

        <!-- cache implementation --> 
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider"/> 

        <!-- store the second-level cache entries in a more human-friendly format --> 
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries" value="true"/> 

        <!-- enable/disable the query cache --> 
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>

    </properties>
```

I am including all my dependencies in my pom.xml. Can somebody will give some insight which property is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474159/hibernate-second-level-cache-with-spring/931961#931961). Check if you are reading your settings from persistence.xml instead of your Spring context.