# Spring boot +Spring data JPA +Second-level cache giving mutate error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am having an application with **mutiple datasource** using Spring Boot and Spring data JPA.

I am getting the below exception `hibernate.cache.region.factory_class` not set, though I am setting it in code. Spring Boot is checking for it before I set, or not able to read my setting.

```
caused by: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given; please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory using the hibernate.cache.region.factory_class setting and make sure the second level cache provider (hibernate-infinispan, e.g.) is available on the classpath.
       at org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCachingRegionFactory.buildEntityRegion(NoCachingRegionFactory.java:83)
       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:364)
       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852)
       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845)
       at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844)
       at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:338)
       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
       ... 130 more

8-Nov-2015 00:23:46.220 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive D:\sw\apache-tomcat-8.0.23\webapps\SecurityValidator.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SecurityValidator]]
```

I am having the below code. Only relevant parts are pasted:-

Spring Boot configuation class to show the excluding auto configurations:-

```
@EnableAsync
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,})
@ComponentScan("com.demo")
public class Initializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
```

My two datasource configuations:-

```
 @Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean certEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(certificateDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "dao.entity.cert" });
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties1.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
        properties1.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties1);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
        properties.setProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true");
        properties.setProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");
        properties.setProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.default_cache_concurrency_strategy", "NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE");
        properties.setProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region_prefix", "valCache");
        properties.setProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries", "false");
        properties.setProperty("spring.jpa.properties.h4m.adapter.class", "kr.pe.kwonnam.hibernate4memcached.spymemcached.SpyMemcachedAdapter");
        properties.setProperty("spring.jpa.properties.h4m.timestamper.class", "kr.pe.kwonnam.hibernate4memcached.timestamper.HibernateCacheTimestamperMemcachedImpl");

        properties.setProperty("spring.jpa.properties.h4m.adapter.spymemcached.hosts", "localhost:11211");
        properties.setProperty("spring.jpa.properties.h4m.adapter.spymemcached.hashalgorithm", "KETAMA_HASH");
        properties.setProperty("spring.jpa.properties.h4m.adapter.spymemcached.operation.timeout.millis", "5000");
        properties.setProperty("spring.jpa.properties.h4m.adapter.spymemcached.transcoder", "kr.pe.kwonnam.hibernate4memcached.spymemcached.KryoTranscoder");
        properties.setProperty("spring.jpa.properties.h4m.adapter.spymemcached.cachekey.prefix", "vali");
        properties.setProperty("spring.jpa.properties.h4m.adapter.spymemcached.kryotranscoder.compression.threashold.bytes", "20000");


        properties.setProperty("spring.jpa.properties.h4m.expiry.seconds", "600");

        properties.setProperty("spring.jpa.properties.h4m.expiry.seconds.valCache.org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache", "86400");

        properties.setProperty("spring.jpa.properties.h4m.expiry.seconds.valCache.org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache", "3600");


        properties.setProperty("spring.jpa.properties.h4m.expiry.seconds.valCache.cert", "1800");
        properties.setProperty("spring.jpa.properties.h4m.expiry.seconds.valCache.users", "1800");
        em.setJpaProperties(properties);

        return em;
    }
```

Similarly for the second data source also:-

```
@Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean userEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
..................
-----------------
}
```

I am using the below dependencies:-

```
</dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>kr.pe.kwonnam.hibernate4memcached</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate4-memcached-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.7</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>kr.pe.kwonnam.hibernate4memcached</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate4-memcached-spymemcached-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>0.7</version>
        </dependency>
```

Any suggestions or pointers is also welcomed.

**UPDATE ERROR**

I am still not able to move fully forward, but I am getting the below error now.

```
Caused by: net.spy.memcached.OperationTimeoutException: Mutate operation timed out,unable to modify counter [validator.validatorCache.users@]
        at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.mutate(MemcachedClient.java:1663) ~[spymemcached-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.mutateWithDefault(MemcachedClient.java:1835) ~[spymemcached-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.incr(MemcachedClient.java:1767) ~[spymemcached-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
        at kr.pe.kwonnam.hibernate4memcached.spymemcached.SpyMemcachedAdapter.getNamespacedKey(SpyMemcachedAdapter.java:141) ~[hibernate4-memcached-spymemcached-adapter-0.7.jar:na]
        at kr.pe.kwonnam.hibernate4memcached.spymemcached.SpyMemcachedAdapter.set(SpyMemcachedAdapter.java:167) ~[hibernate4-memcached-spymemcached-adapter-0.7.jar:na]
        at kr.pe.kwonnam.hibernate4memcached.regions.GeneralDataMemcachedRegion.put(GeneralDataMemcachedRegion.java:86) ~[hibernate4-memcached-core-0.7.jar:na]
        at kr.pe.kwonnam.hibernate4memcached.strategies.MemcachedRegionAccessStrategy.putFromLoad(MemcachedRegionAccessStrategy.java:52) ~[hibernate4-memcached-core-0.7.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:221) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1115) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:973) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:921) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:67) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:315) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:67) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
```

I corrected the properties setting, by removing the properties bit. It was a typo. But now I am getting the above error.

Comment: Found a similar question:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/474159/hibernate-second-level-cache-with-spring.But still not able to resolve. :(

Answer (score 0):

The error `net.spy.memcached.OperationTimeoutException: Mutate operation timed out` appears to completely refer to memcached client/server interaction. Most likely the memcached server is not available on `localhost:11211`.

Answer (score -2):

Can you try the below factory class:

> net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory

or

> org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.Si­ngletonEhCacheRegionFactory

Also, to debug - I would probably go ahead and check the actual jars and look for the presence of the factory class in that jar.

Comment: Thanks Ashwini for the comment.I had checked the class in the jar. It is present in the jar. And still it throws the exception.

Comment: I checked the options mentioned in the answer. No luck:(.

Comment: I also checked "kr.pe.kwonnam.hibernate4memcached.Hibernate4MemcachedRegionFactory" factory class, without any change in the exception.

Comment: Sure. Will try that. But I am assuming that Spring boots auto configuration is causing the problem here and was looking for ways to exclude the caching , so that my custom bean implementation is taken. I feel, though I am setting all fields, the auto configuration is trying to pick it even before i load the bean.