# Memcached with Spring for mutiple data source not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, memcached

I have a Spring boot+Spring data JPA application using two datasource. I have configured the entity manager using LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean as below:

```
 @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean userEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(userDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "uk.co.o2.smip.validator.dao.entity.user" });
        em.setSharedCacheMode(SharedCacheMode.ALL);
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
```

This worked fine for me.
**Adding caching for two datasource**
Then i wanted to add memcached to this. I added the properties to setJpaPropertyMap. **But still i am getting the error hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given**

I have set the below properties:

```
properties.put("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
    properties.put("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true");
    properties.put("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "kr.pe.kwonnam.hibernate4memcached.Hibernate4MemcachedRegionFactory");
    properties.put("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.default_cache_concurrency_strategy", "NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE");
    properties.put("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region_prefix", "validatorCache");
    properties.put("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries", "false");
    properties.put("spring.jpa.properties.h4m.adapter.class", "kr.pe.kwonnam.hibernate4memcached.spymemcached.SpyMemcachedAdapter");
    properties.put("spring.jpa.properties.h4m.timestamper.class", "kr.pe.kwonnam.hibernate4memcached.timestamper.HibernateCacheTimestamperMemcachedImpl");

    properties.put("spring.jpa.properties.h4m.adapter.spymemcached.hosts", "localhost:11211");
    properties.put("spring.jpa.properties.h4m.adapter.spymemcached.hashalgorithm", "KETAMA_HASH");
    properties.put("spring.jpa.properties.h4m.adapter.spymemcached.operation.timeout.millis", "5000");
    properties.put("spring.jpa.properties.h4m.adapter.spymemcached.transcoder", "kr.pe.kwonnam.hibernate4memcached.spymemcached.KryoTranscoder");
    properties.put("spring.jpa.properties.h4m.adapter.spymemcached.cachekey.prefix", "validator");
    properties.put("spring.jpa.properties.h4m.adapter.spymemcached.kryotranscoder.compression.threashold.bytes", "20000");


    properties.put("spring.jpa.properties.h4m.expiry.seconds", "600");

    properties.put("spring.jpa.properties.h4m.expiry.seconds.validatorCache.org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache", "86400");

    properties.put("spring.jpa.properties.h4m.expiry.seconds.validatorCache.org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache", "3600");


   // properties.put("spring.jpa.properties.h4m.expiry.seconds.validatorCache.certificates", "1800");
    properties.put("spring.jpa.properties.h4m.expiry.seconds.validatorCache.users", "1800");
```

I have checked that the mentioned class files are there in the classpath. Dont have any idea whats going wrong.

Exception

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given; please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory using the hibernate.cache.region.factory_class setting and make sure the second level cache provider (hibernate-infinispan, e.g.) is available on the classpath.
        at org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCachingRegionFactory.buildEntityRegion(NoCachingRegionFactory.java:83)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:364)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:338)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
        ... 130 more
```

Comment: How did you check that it is on the classpath?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring boot +Spring data JPA Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory\_class is not given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769824/spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-second-level-cache-is-used-in-the-application-but)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Exploded the war, when to the dependent jar file in the lib folder and checked if the mentioned class file is there.

Comment: Is Memcached itself on the classpath?

Comment: Sorry. I didnt get your question? i mean kr.pe.kwonnam.hibernate4memcached.Hibernate4MemcachedRegionFactory is in the class path.

Comment: This question looks similar.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/474159/hibernate-second-level-cache-with-spring. But i am setting the properties directly, rather than properties file. Still getting the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95466/discussion-between-manu-and-dragan-bozanovic).